# Imagick NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509 while reading PDF in WAMP

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, imagick

I have installed Imagick 3.4.4 in my WAMP using the steps defined here: https://newsinfo-blog.blogspot.com/2015/03/install-imagick-on-wamp-server.html

I then use the following code to convert a PDF to a JPEG image:

```
    $im = new Imagick();

    $im->setResolution(300,300);
    $im->readImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/codeigniter/assets/lofthouse.pdf[0]');
    $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
    $im->writeImage('thumblofthouse.jpg');
    $im->clear();
    $im->destroy();
```

But I am getting the following error message :

> An unknown error has occurred Type: ImagickException
>
> Message: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `PDF' @
>   error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509

What am i doing wrong? How can I save the first page of a PDF as an image?

I have noted that when I try :

```
print_r(Imagick::queryFormats());
```

the result is an empty array.

EDIT:

These are the steps I have undertaken so far:

1. Downloaded ImageMagick https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows and installed it via the installer, put it in my D:\software folder.
2. Downloaded & installed Ghostscript : https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html , placed it in D:\ folder, and ticked the checkbox to generate the fonts.
3. Copied the php_imagick.dll file to my /ext/ folder
4. Copied over all the CORE_RL_* files to apache/bin/ folder
5. Added the root path to the installation directory of ImageMagick in my PATH variables (and put it way above the PHP line)

EDIT2:
I've also done the following steps, although i'm definitely not sure whether these are needed

- Created a new system variable called MAGICK_HOME and let it point to the imagemagick root directory.
- modified the policy.xml in ImageMagick by adding `<policy domain="module" pattern="{PS,PDF,XPS}" rights="read|write"/>` in the policymap attribute.

This is what phpinfo() returns:

```
imagick module  enabled
imagick module version  3.4.4
imagick classes Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version   ImageMagick 7.0.7-11 Q16 x86 2017-11-23 http://www.imagemagick.org
Imagick using ImageMagick library version   ImageMagick 7.0.7-11 Q16 x86 2017-11-23 http://www.imagemagick.org
ImageMagick copyright   Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
ImageMagick release date    2017-11-23
ImageMagick number of supported formats:    0
```

EDIT3: I am able to convert PDF to JPG via the commandline using ImageMagick. After all the steps above, i'm now getting the following error:

```
Type: ImagickException

Message: no decode delegate for this image format `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509
```

Comment: You need to install `Ghostscript` to enable **ImageMagick** to read PDFs.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Hello Mark! Thanks for your reply. I have edited my original question with all the exact steps I have already undertaken, but the error remains the exact same.

Comment: Can you create and access a page which runs `phpinfo();`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have added additional information and the output of phpinfo() in the question! Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Number of supported formats is looking rather low! It's been ages since I did this, so if anyone else has better advice, I'll shut up. You should be able to find a file called `delegates.xml` and there should be an entry in there with `PDF` and `&quot;gs&quot;` You may need to point this explicitly at your `ghostscript` binary in your `D:\Software`

Comment: @MarkSetchell There's no mention of gs in the delegates.xml file whatsoever. It's important to note that I am able to convert PDF to JPG via ImageMagick command line, but it's just via imagick that i'm getting the "no decode delegate for this image format `PDF'" error

Comment: PHP uses a different set of PATH variables. So it cannot find Ghostscript. Mark is correct. You need to specifically add the path to Ghostscript where it says: `command="&quot;gs&quot;` (note the gs in there) in ` <delegate decode="ps" encode="pdf" mode="bi" command="&quot;gs&quot; -sstdout=%%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 &quot;-sDEVICE=pdfwrite&quot; &quot;-sOutputFile=%o&quot; &quot;-f%i&quot;"/>` in the delegates.xml file and in any other similar places

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me. Solved.

**Check your file extension, be sure to have '.pdf'**

Note : in my case ifpdf version is 1.4 or less, a bad or empty extension is not a problem, conversion will work, but for new pdf version i got exception "no delegated...".

Comment: See my comment above and all the steps the OP listed that he did. This was my command that worked fine. ` magick rose: \( +clone  -background navy  -shadow 80x3+5+5 \) +swap -background none   -layers merge  +repage   shadow.png`